# Error message when running jmeter test

Tags: jmeter

When I run test in jmeter, error message is displayed as setRunning(false, *local*) and no result in shown in view results.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqcK7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the similar issue way back.. this helped me
you need to listener, for example Sampler-> HTTP Request

Comment: listener as in? could you explain more about it?

Comment: see this to learn about listener and how you can configure it http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see any [Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) in your Test Plan. Samplers do the actual work so you need to have at least one to do something. Once done - you will see the result in the listener.

A good starting point would be recording your test scenario using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension)

See [Building a Web Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html) JMeter User Manual chapter for more details.

Comment: thanx for suggestion.. its fixed!